# Kafka Salesforce sink connector - The Kafka record is missing the key _ObjectType which is used to identify the SObject

Tags: salesforce, apache-kafka-connect

I am using confluent cloud to sink some data from Kafka to Salesforce via SObject Sink connector. The connection is made but I am running into an error "The Kafka record is missing the key _ObjectType which is used to identify the SObject. Please include the _ObjectType field in the record". Anyone has an idea of what is going wrong error?

Google searches aren't that useful as they lead me to Kafka Key/Value concept which is primarily for maintaining order of the messages

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sink random records that you've created externally to the other connectors?

From [overview docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-salesforce/current/overview.html)

> The Salesforce SObjects sink connector requires the Kafka records to have the same structure and format as the records output by the PushTopic source connector

So, if you aren't *also* using the "PushTopic source connector" or have records that deviate from the "structure and format" of those events (SObjects), then you should expect to see some error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right. You have to pass in the "Id" attribute along with its value in order to successfully write to salesforce. Because Id is the column which its value helps to identify if published record already exist or to be treated as an insert. Please try to pass in Id along with it value for example here in below I passed JSON payload as I have JSON converter in my configuration file for the connector.

```
"payload": {
  "Id": "124421",
  "FirstName": "name",
}
```